# How to get a key from Object values?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, key

I'm trying to build a chord dictionary which has as key the name of the chords and as value an array with the MIDI numbers (the notes) which the chords are made of. I'm having a problem though, I can't get the key of the dictionary once I give as input of the function getkey() the array of midi numbers..What should I do? Thanks in advance :)

```js
 var dictionary = {
  "Cmaj7": [60,64,67,71]
};

const getKey = (obj,val) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === val);

console.log(getKey(dictionary,[60,64,67,71]));
```

Comment: You're comparing different objects in memory.

Comment: `dictionary.Cmaj7 !== val`

Comment: So how should I change the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dictionary = {
  "Cmaj7": [60,64,67,71]
};

function getKey(obj, arr) {

  // Find the first object that satisfies the condition...
  const found = Object.entries(obj).find(([key, notes]) => {

    // ...that all the notes in the object are included in the
    // array that was passed in. As long as the notes array and the
    // query array are the same length, the notes can be in any order
    return arr.length === notes.length && arr.every(note => notes.includes(note));
  });

  // If `found` is an Object.entries array return the key
  // otherwise return the error
  return found && found[0] || 'Key not found';
}

// Same order
const key = getKey(dictionary, [60, 64, 67, 71]);
console.log(key);

// Different order
const key2 = getKey(dictionary, [71, 64, 67, 60]);
console.log(key2);

// Missing note
const key3 = getKey(dictionary, [71, 64, 60]);
console.log(key3);
```

Comment: Hi! I've got another issue but it came while working on my project..now I have two identical vectors that can be refferred to two different keys..but I don't know how to make you function returning me two different keys for two identical values (arrays) What can be done? thank you in advance :)

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, here's the link to my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709238/how-to-obtain-different-keys-which-have-same-values-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `===` operator to compare two arrays. Use the following function:

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
  if(a.length != b.length) return false;
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Just replace `obj[key] === val` with `compareArrays(obj[key], val)` and it should work, assuming that all values are going to be simple arrays. If not, you want to check for that in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're searching for arrays, you can use the function `every` for checking each value is `included` within the array `val`.

*This is assuming we are working on arrays*

```js
var dictionary = {"Cmaj7": [60,64,67,71]},
    getKey = (obj,val) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key].length === val.length && obj[key].every((kn) => val.includes(kn)));

console.log(getKey(dictionary,[60,64,71,67]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But I noticed that it isn't gonna work If I wanna put in the getKey() function the array with the same elements but in a random order (because when I play a midi keyboard MIDI message could be received randomly), what can be changed?