# How to obtain different keys which have same values in a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, key

I have a dictionary like this one and as you can see, I have two identical array values for two different keys. My question is: how can I get these two keys by giving in input one values? I'd like to obtain as output all the keys that have the same values. This is because in my project I can only use sharp or flat (not both) in the detection of a note.

```js
var dictionary = {
  "Cmaj7": ["C","E","G","B"] ,     //majors
  "C#maj7": ["C#","F","G#","C"],
  "Dbmaj7":["C#","F","G#","C"]}
```

Comment: Are the value arrays always sorted in the same way?

Comment: Hi! No, they both can be in a random order as well. What cares is that they contains the same string values

Comment: array filter, every, and includes?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var dictionary = {
  "Cmaj7": ["C","E","G","B"] ,     //majors
  "C#maj7": ["C#","F","G#","C"],
  "Dbmaj7":["C#","F","G#","C"]}
  
var newObj = {}
for (var o in dictionary) {
  var reverseKey = dictionary[o].join("_");
  if (!newObj[reverseKey]) newObj[reverseKey]=[];
  newObj[reverseKey].push(o);
}
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this via `Array.filter`,`Array.every`, `Array.some` and `Array.includes` like this:

```js
var data = { "Cmaj7": ["C", "E", "G", "B"], "C#maj7": ["C#", "F", "G#", "C"], "Dbmaj7": ["C#", "F", "G#", "C"] }

const e = Object.entries(data)
const dubs = e.filter(([k1, v1]) => v1.every(v => e.some(([k2, v2]) => k1 != k2 && v2.includes(v))))
const result = dubs.reduce((acc,[k,v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {})

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to get the values of each key and filter then so that every one of the values are included in the rest of the object values.

You can also just get an array of the keys with same values via `Array.reduce` and `Array.filter`:

```js
var data = { "Cmaj7": ["C", "E", "G", "B"], "C#maj7": ["C#", "F", "G#", "C"], "Dbmaj7": ["C#", "F", "G#", "C"] }

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k,v], i, a) => {
  let key = v.join('-')
  r[key] = [...r[key] || [], k]
  return i == a.length-1 ? Object.values(r).filter(a => a.length > 1) : r
}, {})

console.log(...result)
```